# How to setup Jersey on Jetty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jetty

Here are my relevant files.

POM file: http://pastebin.com/ZPTWifys
web.xml file: http://pastebin.com/7kd8Et6Y
JAX-RS resource: http://pastebin.com/ddwDEwNK

I do a mvn clean install - works fine. I point my browser to localhost:8080/firstjersey. I get the "Hello World" index page. Then I try pointing my browser to localhost:8080/firstjersey/resources/test, and I get nothing. I try localhost:8080/resources/test, and get nothing. The problem is that I am simply unable to access my resource. I don't know if it's even being scanned by the servlet container. But everything in my configuration looks right. What's wrong?

I appreciate all help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet mapping should include a wildcard:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```